# SQLite Database not updating properly after deleting row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

When I delete any data then listitem click is showing error when opening listitem and data are also not correct on custom listview. After deleting row 0  data is not updating properly. Please help..

```
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");
        if (Value > 0) {
            // means this is the view part not the add contact part.
            Cursor crs = mydb.getData(Value);
            id_To_Update = Value;
            crs.moveToFirst();
            String nam = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.C_NAME));
            String phon = crs.getString(crs
                    .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.C_PHONE));
            String addr = crs.getString(crs
                    .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.C_ADDRESS));
            String dat = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.C_DATE));
            String typ = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.C_TYPE));
            if (!crs.isClosed()) {
                crs.close();
            }
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            name.setText((CharSequence) nam);
            name.setFocusable(false);
            name.setClickable(false);

            phone.setText((CharSequence) phon);
            phone.setFocusable(false);
            phone.setClickable(false);

            type.setText((CharSequence) typ);
            type.setFocusable(false);
            type.setClickable(false);

            address.setText((CharSequence) addr);
            address.setFocusable(false);
            address.setClickable(false);

            date.setText((CharSequence) dat);
            date.setFocusable(false);
            date.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
}



    case R.id.Delete_Contact:

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Deleted Successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        com.example.addressbook.MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog d = builder.create();
        d.setTitle("Are you sure");
        d.show();

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

public void run(View view) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");
        if (Value > 0) {
            if (mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update, name.getText().toString(),
                    phone.getText().toString(), type.getText().toString(),
                    address.getText().toString(), date.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        com.example.addressbook.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            if (mydb.insertContact(name.getText().toString(), phone
                    .getText().toString(), type.getText().toString(),
                    address.getText().toString(), date.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    com.example.addressbook.MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

DBHelper.java

```
public Integer deleteContact(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("contacts", "id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}
```

}

Comment: please give us the error, and try to locate the code that produces it...

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(15486): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

It is showing error after deleting row. It's actually not updating list view properly after deleting.

Comment: could you please edit your post and give us only the funtion that does the update? And provide a sample of the table you are using

Comment: You must be trying to delete some record on a table that is empty by itself, hence the message you are getting.

Comment: is it possible that You want to delete only row number 0? If yes, You are trying to delete an entry with id=0, but this is not necessarily the entry number 0?

Comment: Here deleteContact() method has some problem. I think so because after deleting row data is not loading on list item click. It should be updated but I could not understand how?

Comment: What value does deleteContact() method returns to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have got the solution. I have a text view in custom list view which has Table id which is unique for every row and after deleting the row it's value does not change so I am opening the data of that row on different activity.